# Angular BrowserModule for NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

As we use `BrowserModule` for using `ngModel` in web area, and is imported by default while creating new `ng` app, what is the equivalent for this in NativeScript?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jannomeister I want to use `ngModel` in nativescript app. NativeScript team has own equivalents for Angular's core modules. Is there anything for `BrowserModule`  or we can just use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ngModel` to nativescript app, you could use `NativeScriptFormsModule` and import it to your `app.module.ts` as following:

```
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from "nativescript-angular/forms"
```

you can check this link [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/angular-data-binding)